# How to get job deatil from odoo 9.0 using xml-rpc

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, odoo-9

I am trying to get job positions from odoo 9.0 in .NET which is working fine. The object for job positions is "hr.job".

```
XmlRpcStruct[] JobPositions = odooProxyObject.Read("odoodb", userid, "awais", "hr.job", "read", new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 30 }, new string[] { "id", "name" });
```

I want to get detail of a specific job position. What will be the object for job details?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. We need to mention the attributes we want for all the jobs like "id", "name", "department_id", "description", "no_of_employee", "no_of_recruitment", "expected_employees", "no_of_hired_employee", "state".

```
XmlRpcStruct[] JobPositions = odooProxyObject.Read(dbname, UserID, password, "hr.job", "read", new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, new string[] { "id", "name", "department_id", "description", "no_of_employee", "no_of_recruitment", "expected_employees", "no_of_hired_employee", "state" });
        return JobPositions;
```